How to define complex valued spherical coordinates?
I am currently tackling an optimization problem involving complex valued vectors. However the optimization is solely about finding the optimal "direction" of the vector. So any (complex-valued) scaling does not matter, i.e. $\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{opt,2}} = \alpha \cdot \mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{opt,1}}$ To make the optimization procedure (currently gradient descent) faster and more robust I want to constraint the optimization to reduce these unneccessary two degrees of freedom.
Main question: Is there something like complex-valued spherical coordinates so I can translate my problem into coordinates which have one degree of freedom less?
Side question: Is there something like constraint gradient descent for my purpose (Maybe similar to Lagragian optimization, but in my case there is likely no closed-form solution) ?
The optimization problem is formulated with complex-valued cartesian coordinates whereby $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{v}}$ is a projection matrix depending on solely the "direction" of $\mathbf{v}$, i.e. $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{P}_{\alpha\mathbf{v}}\quad\forall\quad \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$
To reduce a degree of freedom here I introduced the constraint of unit-norm.
$\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{opt}} = \mathrm{argmin}_{\mathbf{v}}  \left(\mathrm{trace}(\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{v}}^{\mathrm{H}})\right) \quad\mathrm{s.t.}\quad \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{v} = 1 $ (my main question is how to formulate this optimization problem in complex valued spherical coordinates so that the constraint is intrinsic in the optimization space.)
Since the arbitrary scaling factor $\alpha$ is complex-valued so it has a magnitude and a phase I want to introduce something like unit-norm and unit-phase. I did not find anything about unit-phase but for my purpose the following constraint whould work because it reduces 2 real-valued degrees of freedom of the optimization problem, in contrast to the first constraint which just removes only one real-valued degree of freedom, i.e.
$\mathbf{v}_{\mathrm{opt}} = \mathrm{argmin}_{\mathbf{v}}  \left(\mathrm{trace}(\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{v}}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{v}}^{\mathrm{H}})\right) \quad\mathrm{s.t.}\quad \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{v} = 1 $
